# Extracting Text from WPF

Tags: wpf, text

i have some xaml files that include text, this text is in paterns, like this paths and canvas
i need a way to convert them to row text; thank you

```
<Path Data="M603.0815,627.8994C590.7485,627.8994,580.7505,617.9014,580.7505,605.5674C580.7505,593.2354,590.7485,583.2374,603.0815,583.2374C615.4145,583.2374,625.4115,593.2354,625.4115,605.5674C625.4115,617.9014,615.4145,627.8994,603.0815,627.8994z" Height="45.677" Canvas.Left="504.149" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1.015" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" Canvas.Top="482.064" Width="45.676"/>
            <Canvas Height="45.311" Canvas.Left="500.553" Opacity="0.7599949836730957" Canvas.Top="478.508" Width="45.309">
                <Canvas Height="45.311" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="45.309">
                    <Canvas.Clip>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M584.42,624.485 C574.056,614.12 574.055,597.314 584.42,586.948 C594.786,576.583 611.591,576.583 621.956,586.948 z" FillRule="Nonzero">
                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,-576.646606445313,-579.174255371094"/>
                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Canvas.Clip>
                    <Path Data="F1M584.42,624.485C574.056,614.12,574.055,597.314,584.42,586.948C594.786,576.583,611.591,576.583,621.956,586.948z" Height="45.311" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="45.309">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.562,0.679" StartPoint="0.454,0.215">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                        <Path.OpacityMask>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.562,0.679" StartPoint="0.454,0.215">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0.6782913, 0, 0, 0" Offset="0.080963134765625"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0.4013089, 0, 0, 0" Offset="0.18010848760604858"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0.178047657, 0, 0, 0" Offset="0.31294554471969604"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0.02753514, 0, 0, 0" Offset="0.54220128059387207"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0, 0, 0, 0" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#0, 0, 0, 0" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.OpacityMask>
                    </Path>
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
            <Path Data="F1M232.805,421.572C229.604,421.572,226.683,422.892,224.564,425.017L224.564,425.017C222.448,427.145,221.128,430.081,221.128,433.312L221.128,433.312L221.128,439.382L221.128,472.247C221.128,475.478,222.446,478.415,224.566,480.544L224.566,480.544C226.683,482.667,229.599,483.987,232.807,483.987L232.807,483.987L327.873,483.987C331.076,483.987,333.995,482.667,336.113,480.544L336.113,480.544C338.232,478.415,339.548,475.478,339.548,472.247L339.548,472.247L339.548,453.323L339.548,447.284L339.548,433.312C339.548,430.081,338.233,427.145,336.111,425.017L336.111,425.017C333.995,422.892,331.078,421.572,327.873,421.572L327.873,421.572z M222.652,460.445L222.652,433.312C222.652,430.513,223.792,427.968,225.632,426.124L225.632,426.124C227.471,424.275,230.009,423.128,232.805,423.128L232.805,423.128L327.873,423.128C330.667,423.128,333.206,424.275,335.048,426.124L335.048,426.124C336.883,427.968,338.026,430.513,338.026,433.312L338.026,433.312L338.026,447.284L338.024,453.323L338.024,472.247C338.024,475.046,336.884,477.591,335.047,479.434L335.047,479.434C333.206,481.285,330.667,482.43,327.873,482.43L327.873,482.43L232.807,482.43C230.011,482.43,227.471,481.285,225.63,479.434L225.63,479.434C223.792,477.591,222.652,475.046,222.652,472.247L222.652,472.247z" Height="62.415" Canvas.Left="145.034" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="320.906" Width="118.42">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0" StartPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.080001801252365112"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF878687" Offset="0.69325298070907593"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.307234675, 0.303684026, 0.307234675" Offset="0.88050458675388654"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.448453128, 0.445626259, 0.448453128" Offset="0.92941428201599052"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.6357934, 0.6339267, 0.6357934" Offset="0.96216528915308075"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.859842, 0.8591236, 0.859842" Offset="0.98765014041117993"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
            <Canvas Height="57.274" Canvas.Left="147.674" Opacity="0.5" Canvas.Top="323.477" Width="113.02">
                <Canvas Height="57.274" Canvas.Left="0" Opacity="0.38999900221824646" Canvas.Top="0" Width="113.02">
                    <Path Data="M336.788,456.73L336.788,434.419C336.788,428.765,332.133,424.143,326.449,424.143L320.519,424.143L305.105,424.143L234.111,424.143C228.425,424.143,223.769,428.765,223.769,434.419L223.769,456.73L223.768,439.382L223.768,471.14C223.768,476.795,228.422,481.417,234.107,481.417L240.037,481.417L255.451,481.417L326.444,481.417C332.128,481.417,336.783,476.795,336.783,471.14L336.783,439.382z" Height="57.274" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="113.02">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="-0.039,0.5" StartPoint="1.213,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC5C5C5" Offset="0.69325298070907593"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.5962005, 0.5962005, 0.5962005" Offset="0.88050458675388654"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.678514, 0.678514, 0.678514" Offset="0.92941428201599052"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.787711, 0.787711, 0.787711" Offset="0.96216528915308075"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="sc#1, 0.9183046, 0.9183046, 0.9183046" Offset="0.98765014041117993"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas Height="46.997" Canvas.Left="147.674" Canvas.Top="323.477" Width="113.02">
                <Canvas.Clip>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M320.519,424.143 L305.105,424.143 L234.112,424.143 C228.425,424.143 223.769,428.765 223.769,434.419 L223.769,434.419 L223.769,456.731 L223.768,439.382 L223.768,471.14 C243.672,458.167 336.788,434.419 336.788,434.419 L336.788,434.419 C336.788,428.765 332.133,424.143 326.449,424.143 L326.449,424.143 z" FillRule="Nonzero">
                        <PathGeometry.Transform>
                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,0,0,1,-223.768005371094,-424.143005371094"/>
                        </PathGeometry.Transform>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Canvas.Clip>
                <Path Data="F1M320.519,424.143L305.105,424.143L234.112,424.143C228.425,424.143,223.769,428.765,223.769,434.419L223.769,434.419L223.769,456.731L223.768,439.382L223.768,471.14C243.672,458.167,336.788,434.419,336.788,434.419L336.788,434.419C336.788,428.765,332.133,424.143,326.449,424.143L326.449,424.143z" Height="46.997" Canvas.Left="0" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="0" Width="113.02">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="-0.039,0.5" StartPoint="1.213,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Path.Fill>
                    <Path.OpacityMask>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="-0.039,0.5" StartPoint="1.213,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="sc#0.5, 0, 0, 0" Offset="0.22740978002548218"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="sc#0, 0, 0, 0" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Path.OpacityMask>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
```

Comment: When you say "convert them to row text," what do you mean?  What output are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how it is done in the Microsoft Sample Application called locbaml.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider an XmlDataProvider together with a suitable XPath, or an XslTransform like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for the help but Its XAML not xml --- plus i need to create an application that read wpf and extract the text then save the text